# Facing issue with link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using link_to in the following manner in view:

```
<td><%=link_to("https://www.google.com/")%></td>
```

But on hovering/clicking on the link still redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/`. How do I redirect it to Google.

Comment: try this `<%= link_to "Google", "http://google.com" %>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><%=link_to("https://www.google.com/", "https://www.google.com/")%></td>
```

More details here: [link_to doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 0):

after `link_to` you have to describe the name what you want to show as link then pass your link. like this:

```
   <td> <%= link_to "Google", "http://www.google.com" %> </td>
```

For more info: **[Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)**